# GMail "All Mail" not showing anything from last 30 days on Nexus 7 or Nexus 10

Tags: gmail, nexus-7

All the other labels are correct and synced according to their various settings.  There is no particular setting for "All Mail"

Today, I only see up to June 24.  When I scroll to the bottom it adds older messages as expected.

Tomorrow, it will add June 25's email to the All Mail Folder.  It's been doing this ever since I got the Nexus 7 nearly two weeks ago.

I have no problems on a Samsung Galaxy Note (same account, but obviously running ICS and not JB).  When I have already filed everything, I can go to All Mail and see the messages which recently came in, regardless of their labels.

This behavior is not happening on a Google Apps Domain account in the same Nexus but is happening on a Gmail account

Update: Just got a Nexus 10 and problem immediately occurred, and still occurring on 7 with latest 4.2.

I have tried setting the date forward, but no new mail shows up until real time passes.  The unread message count on the left shows the count of unread messages in "all mail", but none of those (recent) unread messages show up in the actual message list on the right (in the tablet dual-view)

I have submitted this as a bug several times to Google but with no result.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/qzl9uUvk3p8/eFyD6HwkuJIJ

Here is the output from ADB LogCat from the time I disable and re-enable sync and go into mail and tap on All mail until the screen is finished loading:

```
D/SyncManager(  432): setSyncAutomatically:  provider gmail-ls, user 0 -> false
D/dalvikvm(20305): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 7% free 9152K/9784K, paused 5ms+11ms, total 41ms
D/SyncManager(  432): setSyncAutomatically:  provider gmail-ls, user 0 -> true
I/ActivityManager(  432): Start proc com.google.android.gm for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailSyncAdapterService: pid=21085 uid=10018 gids={50018, 3003, 1015, 1028}
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub com.google.android.gm2.accountcache: com.android.mail.providers.GmailAccountCacheProvider
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 277K, 5% free 7638K/8020K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 37ms
D/ActivityThread(21085): Loading provider com.android.gmail.ui: com.google.android.gm.provider.UiProvider
D/dalvikvm(20305): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 7% free 9147K/9808K, paused 8ms+7ms, total 43ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 8% free 7687K/8304K, paused 7ms+2ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub gmail-ls: com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub com.google.android.gm: com.google.android.gm.provider.PublicContentProvider
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub com.google.android.gm2.conversation.provider: com.android.mail.browse.GmailConversationProvider
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub com.google.android.gm.suggestionsprovider: com.android.mail.providers.SuggestionsProvider
I/ActivityThread(21085): Pub com.android.gmail.ui: com.google.android.gm.provider.UiProvider
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 373K, 7% free 7755K/8304K, paused 4ms+20ms, total 51ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 285K, 6% free 7897K/8336K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 35ms
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 358K, 6% free 8015K/8516K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 29ms
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 7077919, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 201K, 5% free 8327K/8680K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 34ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 446K, 7% free 8362K/8952K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 42ms
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 475K, 7% free 8401K/9028K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 25ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 8% free 8370K/9060K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
I/Gmail   (21085): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_EXPLICIT freed 301K, 8% free 8414K/9060K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 38ms
I/Gmail   (21085): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 7077940, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (21085): lowestBackward conversation id 0
D/dalvikvm(20305): GC_CONCURRENT freed 539K, 8% free 9115K/9808K, paused 7ms+11ms, total 62ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 7% free 8454K/9060K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 172ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 185K, 7% free 8475K/9112K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 8% free 8473K/9132K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 186K, 8% free 8472K/9132K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 8% free 8470K/9132K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm(20305): GC_CONCURRENT freed 342K, 6% free 9285K/9808K, paused 5ms+18ms, total 56ms
D/dalvikvm(20267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 6% free 8914K/9472K, paused 16ms+51ms, total 108ms
I/ActivityManager(  432): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 432
I/ActivityManager(  432): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.GmailActivity bnds=[656,595][784,723]} from pid 831
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 229K, 8% free 8489K/9132K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
I/TwoPaneLayout(21085): setting up new TPL, w=800 fw=266 cv=800
D/libEGL  (21085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
D/libEGL  (21085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
D/libEGL  (21085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
D/OpenGLRenderer(21085): Enabling debug mode 0
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 5% free 8725K/9152K, paused 14ms+10ms, total 76ms
I/ActivityManager(  432): Displayed com.google.android.gm/.GmailActivity: +479ms
D/ConversationCursorLoader(21085): Add loader: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525445
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Resumed: Inbox]
I/TwoPaneLayout(21085): onViewModeChanged(2)
I/TwoPaneLayout(21085): conv-list mode layout, x=0/266/800
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 283K, 5% free 8922K/9360K, paused 6ms+12ms, total 54ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): Create: initial creation
I/Gmail   (21085): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 7077940, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (21085): lowestBackward conversation id 0
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525445?limit=50, 182ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of Inbox: 1097539104]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 372K, 6% free 9043K/9572K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 30ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525445, 49ms, 0 results
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 334K, 6% free 9247K/9740K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 29ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done Inbox: 1097539104]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onDataSetChanged()]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 5% free 9600K/10028K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 28ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onRefreshRequired()]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of Inbox: 1097494336]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 739K, 9% free 9573K/10484K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 40ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525445, 21ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done Inbox: 1097494336]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onDataSetChanged()]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 8% free 9694K/10484K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onRefreshRequired()]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of Inbox: 1096355048]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525445, 8ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done Inbox: 1096355048]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() Inbox]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify Inbox: onDataSetChanged()]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 799K, 10% free 9584K/10572K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 52ms
D/ConversationCursorLoader(21085): Reset loader/disable cursor: Inbox
D/ConversationCursorLoader(21085): Add loader: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525444
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Resumed: All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): Create: initial creation
I/Gmail   (21085): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 7077940, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (21085): lowestBackward conversation id 0
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525444?limit=50, 111ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of All mail: 1098489856]
D/dalvikvm(  432): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2545K, 38% free 18794K/30040K, paused 4ms+10ms, total 103ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525444, 133ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done All mail: 1098489856]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onDataSetChanged()]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 575K, 9% free 9631K/10572K, paused 5ms+10ms, total 45ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onRefreshRequired()]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of All mail: 1098541328]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525444, 14ms, 0 results
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done All mail: 1098541328]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onDataSetChanged()]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 567K, 10% free 9612K/10572K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 10% free 9600K/10572K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 590K, 8% free 9738K/10572K, paused 3ms+15ms, total 78ms
I/dalvikvm(21085): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 775K, 9% free 9693K/10620K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 75ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onRefreshRequired()]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [refresh() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Start refresh of All mail: 1098632152]
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 438K, 10% free 9639K/10620K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): ConversationCursor query: content://com.android.gmail.ui/caderoux@gmail.com/conversations/594525444, 82ms, 88 results
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 406K, 10% free 9624K/10620K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Query done All mail: 1098632152]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onRefreshReady(), 1 listeners]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [sync() All mail]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): [Notify All mail: onDataSetChanged()]
I/ConversationCursor(21085): *** Underlying cursor position is -1 asking to move from -1 to 0
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 10% free 9657K/10620K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 6% free 10001K/10620K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 31ms
D/dalvikvm(21085): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing app data?

Comment: @AlEverett Clearing the app data seems to have worked while removing and adding the account did not work.

Comment: Problem seems to be recurring, it's now lost all the mail from after July 6 and only shows that and older mail - same problem with the 30 days...

Comment: Have you checked to be sure the app doesn't have an update available?

Comment: @LorraineW No, there are no new updates for GMail in Play.  There was an answer here, but the problem recurred for that user and they've since deleted their answer.  I think there is a general problem with the app.

Comment: Can you turn off sync for that account, start `adb logcat`, turn on sync again and show the log here?

Comment: Forgot to say, I have a Nexus S with CM 9 and a Nexus 7 with today's update to 4.2, both can sync the mail account with no problem.

Comment: Compare with http://pastebin.com/r7kePgTZ it looks somewhat different.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because I had enabled "Sync last 30 days" for the All Mail folder in account settings → "Manage labels".  Apparently there is some bug which makes it sync everything *but* the last 30 days?  I disabled the sync for that folder and refreshed it a few times until went blank and actually reloaded all mail, including today's.

When I re-enable syncing it breaks again, though.

Comment: I have the same problem of the newest 30 days' E-mails missing from my Android device's "All mail" label.

Comment: This fixed my problem.  Stupid bug that Google should be ashamed to have still not fixed as of  "Android 6.0.1, July 5th, 2016 Security Patch".  I had my setting set to "Sync last 90 days", and you are right, All Mail was only syncing up to exactly 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

In my phone, Gmail allows to configure how many days are to be synchronized, and specific labels are allowed to sync either within that period or completely. These labels include inbox, starred, etc. but not all mail. I think they haven't implemented all mail as an actual label, but if your phone has this day setting, I'd assume it should work.

A workaround while it's not fixed by the developers could be adding an equivalent custom label, such as `# All Mail` or `Archived`, and creating a filter in the web interface to apply that label to all of your incoming and outgoing mail. By starting the label name with a hash, you give it precedence in label listing.

Comment: To be clear, it is only showing messages from OLDER than 30 days (and this is a rolling window of invisibility - newer old messages from October 18th are becoming visible as time passes) in all mail, and only for this account, and only on the Nexus 7 and 10 (not the Galaxy Note) - and changing the day setting doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I use labels so heavily, I'd hate to add another "everything" label to everything, but I guess that's an option...

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes - I just tagged 3GB of messages with the "@" tag - I'm worried my filter isn't going to catch everything though - I had to put a selection of domains it the TO address.

Comment: #1 No #4 4.1.2 failed on Nexus 10 (not checked the 7), 4.2.1 released today still has the problem - I need to make another gmail account instead of all my various apps accounts on different domains.  Right now I'm getting by with my * workaround.

Comment: 4.2.1 is working fine on the Galaxy Note.